# Class not found Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

I'm new to Apache Tomcat and I'm trying to run a simple servlet program but it says class not found.

Java file:

```
package com.mkyong;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServletDemo1 extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Deployment file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mkyong.ServletDemo1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Demo1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Logs:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mkyong/ServletDemo1 (wrong name: ServletDemo1)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2904)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:461)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I needed an additional jar file that was to be added to the classpath i did and it worked thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

You .class (remember, .class) file must be present in Tomcat's classpath. Check that. 
Tomcat startup.bat calls catalina.bat where classpath is set.
Catalina.bat has got a line...

```
echo Using CLASSPATH:       "%CLASSPATH%"
```

This will print classpath on the command prompt window from which you called startup.bat/.sh. Use this and search for your file.
If it is not found, your IDE project configuration is not setup correctly to generate .class and put it in required location, e.g. in Maven, it should go to target/classes.
If issue is after deploying war, unzip war and check classes folder. If not found, your build tool is not setup correctly.